# .Net Obfuscator Problems

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I am building some applications and decided it was time to run my code through an obfuscator. I downloaded and used Eazfuscator.NET and then after installing the application I downloaded Ispy to see just how well the process worked.

What I found was that I could still easily see a lot of the code, for instance most logic on my routines was there in some parts of my background workers. Yes the strings were changed but some poritions which I would consider fairly important were visible.

For instance when I build the application authentication key there are certain items which I attach to the key before I run my encryption. These items were visible in when I used Ispy to view the assembly. The passphrase to my encryption library was concealed, but I feel like this is still more information than I would want someone to be able to see.

My question is - is this normal behavior when using an obfuscator? Or should I be trying other ones?

Comment: I would try other ones.   I have used dotfuscator and with the exception of anonymous types it does very well.  VS2010 also has obfuscation I believe

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I used Eazfuscator and I got really dense, hardcore output. Make sure you're using the latest build. Try tweaking some of the settings.

Comment: I see very few settings. Which are you talking about exactly?

Comment: I used to use Eazfucsator and found it to be the best free one on the market. Output was acceptable.

Comment: remember that obfuscaters only make it difficult to reverse engineer... not impossible!  i found that the free ones aren't as good as the ones you have to pay for.  i am using crypto obfuscator and it has quite a few settings!

Comment: Make sure you run de4dot https://bitbucket.org/0xd4d/de4dot/ to see how much you can reverse the obfuscation. If what you want to protect can be reversed, think twice before making any purchase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following settings for Eazfuscator.NET to get better results:

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "code control flow obfuscation", Exclude = false)]
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "PEVerify", Exclude = false)]
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "encrypt symbol names with password mypassword", Exclude = false)]
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "encrypt resources [compress]", Exclude = false)]
```

in your assembly info file

Comment: These settings you listed worked really wel for the .exe file that comes out of the output. However the class library that is build alongside it has the same settings in the assembly file but I can still see quite a bit of it, such as function parameters. Is there something I need to do special for a class library?

Comment: Are methods or properties are public? By default public in library cannot be obfuscated, because they are public so visible for anybody that is attaching that library.

Comment: Yes the methods are public because I use the same library in various different applications. Am I missing something here, how else would I write a library that I can reuse but it can be obfuscated?

Comment: Try to play with [internalsvisibleto attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) and change public to interal, or look into documentation Eazfuscator.NET I think there is an option there to obfuscate public as well. Something like `[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature = "Apply to type *: apply to member * when public and property: renaming", Exclude = false)]`

Comment: Ok I have most of it working. I decided to use the merge feature as well. However my class library relies on Nlog.dll and I can put the embed Nlog.dll build the application, everything runs without crashing but if I do not have the Nlog.dll present the logging never occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, have no experience with nlog

Comment: Ok I will work on NLog in another topic. Your response above solved my problems with the obfuscator.

Comment: @Marcin Where did you find the info regarding settings for Eazfuscator.NET? Your answer has helped me but interested to get even better results if possible through settings. Many Thanks +1

Comment: @Tur sorry, I'm not using Eazfuscator since it is paid, so I cannot help. Try to contact them, since you are paying customer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) - it has a lot of obfuscation techniques including String Encryption, Control Flow Obfuscation, Method Call Hiding, Resource Protection, etc which results in very hard to read and understand code.

DISCLAIMER: I work for LogicNP Software, the developer of Crypto Obfuscator.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced obfuscation features used to obfuscate
assemblies, so the obfuscated .NET code is much harder to understand or fails to be decompiled.
We can protect.NET application and DLLs with code protection that combines and includes
method level code encryption, anti-reverse engineering, anti-debugging, anti-tampering, and
more to prevent unauthorized access and modification of your assemblies.

I am using FxProtect - .Net Obfuscator. It is really good.

You can try it...       **[.Net Obfuscator](http://www.maycoms.net)**